# Quadratic optimisation with quadratic equality constraints

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming, qcqp

I would like to solve the following optimisation problem:

$$\text{minimize} \quad x'Ax \qquad \qquad \text{subject to} \quad x'Bx = x'Cx = 1$$

Where $A$ is symmetric and $B$ and $C$ are diagonal.

Does anyone have a suggestion for an efficient way of solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: No way in general. Even if $A$ is positive semi definite, the quadratic equality constraints make the problem non-convex.

Comment: Thank you, that is good to know.  The matrices B and C do have an interesting property in my case: B+C=Identity, and the non-zero elements of B and C are non-overlapping, i.e. the two constraints are simply setting the sum-squares of two subsets of $(x_i)$. I am wondering if there might be a way to separate this problem into two optimisations with a single constraint each, which would be a straightforward eigenvalue problem. But I don't see how to do that given that the matrix A is not block-diagonal...

Answer (score 3):

You can have your own opinion as to whether this is efficient in some sense. But if you want to solve the problem, then finding a solution can be considered more efficient than not finding a solution.

Here is the code to solve this using the global optimizer BARON under YALMIP.

```
x=sdpvar(length(A),1)
optimize([x'*B*x==1,x'*C*x==1],x'*A*x,sdpsettings('solver','baron'))
```

Depending on the values of B and C, this can solve quite quickly to find the global minimum.

Given that B and C have non-overlapping non-zeros, per the OP's comment, the constraints are the product of two Riemannian manifolds, so manifold optimization could be used, as for instance with MANOPT https://manopt.org/ . I have no idea how well it will do vs. BARON, but it will not be guaranteed to find a global minimum.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **partial** answer - you can solve for 
$$
\min x'Ax \\
s.t. x'Qx = 1
$$
for $Q=B$ or $Q=C$ precisely through [strong duality](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/qcqp.pdf). Similarly, you could also solve for:
$$
\min x'Ax \\
s.t. x'x = 2
$$
where I have used the fact that $B$ and $C$ are diagonal to have that $x'Bx + x'Cx = x'(B+C)x$.

I'm not sure though how you could combine these various solutions to ensure that you achieve a minimum for your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of solving - let $K$ be sufficiently large, and consider the problem

$$
\min x'(A + K(B-C))x \\
s.t. x'(B-C)x \geq 0 \\
x'x \geq 2
$$
where $K$ is set as a penalty to ensure that the first constraint is tight. The second constraint will necessarily be tight at the minimum.

This problem has two quadratic constraints and *may* be solvable through [strong duality](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/23a0/13ff8265d20d239d13731e95b3dfe67d027f.pdf) -  in particular see Theorem 3.5. Note that you need to solve the dual and then you can check whether there is no duality gap by that Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the answers of MotiNK, since there are only two quadratic constraints you can expect to find a global optimum via a semidefinite relaxation (SDP).

In Matlab with the CVX toolbox installed, you could proceed as follows. As long as the optimal matrix $X$ has rank 1 (which is typically the case, at least when $B$ and $C$ are positive semidefinite and such that $B+C$ is positive definite), then the vector $x$ constructed below is a global optimum.

```
n = 6;
A = randsym(n);
B = diag([rand(n/2, 1) ; zeros(n/2, 1)]);
B = B/trace(B);
C = diag([zeros(n/2, 1) ; rand(n/2, 1)]);
C = C/trace(C);

cvx_begin
    variable X(n, n)
    minimize trace(A*X)
    subject to
        trace(B*X) == 1;
        trace(C*X) == 1;
        X == semidefinite(n);
cvx_end

[V, D] = eig(X);
% Confirm that D(end, end) is the only positive entry.
diag(D)'
% If so, then x is optimal.
x = sqrt(D(end, end))*V(:, end);
```

Alternatively, as Mark L. Stone pointed out, given the special structure of $B$ and $C$, you could also consider using optimization on two spheres.

Indeed, it seems that $x$ is really a concatenation (perhaps with some re-ordering of entries) of two vectors, as $x = [x_1 ; x_2]$ with $x_1 = \tilde B^{-1/2}y_1$ and $x_2 = \tilde C^{-1/2}y_2$ -- here, $\tilde B$ denotes the top-left diagonal block of $B$, and $\tilde C$ denotes the bottom-right diagonal block of $C$.

Essentially, we get $x^\top B x = x_1^\top \tilde B x_1 = y_1^\top y_1 = 1$ if $y_1$ is unit norm.

So they idea is that we can minimize $x^\top A x$, which is really a function of $y_1, y_2$, both unit-norm vectors. That's a homogeneous quadratic cost function to minimize over a product of two spheres.

The non-convexity is not too bad and reasonably well understood. See for example [Corollary 5.8 in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02008) for guarantees if we relax the problem just slightly.